# sum of two cones

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

A non-empty set $K$ of a vector space is called a cone if it satisfies the following:

1. $ K +K \subseteq K,$
2. $\alpha K \subseteq K$ for all $\alpha \ge 0,$
3. $K \cap (-K) ={0}$.

Let $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ be two cones of a vector space. I have proved that if $K_{1} \cap (-K_{2}) = {0}$, then their sum $K_{1}+K_{2}$ is a cone. But I am not sure whether the converse is true, that is if $K_{1}+K_{2}$ is a cone then is it true that $K_{1} \cap (-K_{2}) = {0}$? I guess its not true. But I am not able to find any counter example. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse is also true. Assume that $K_1 \cap (-K_2) \neq 0$ and let $x \in K_1 \cap (-K_2), x \neq 0$. In particular, $x \in K_1, (-x) \in K_2$. Since $0 \in K_1, K_2$ we have $$x = x + 0 \in K_1 + K_2$$ $$x = -(0 +  (-x)) \in -(K_1 + K_2).$$ It follows that $x \in (K_1 + K_2) \cap (-(K_1 + K_2))$ and $x \neq 0$, violating the third property of a cone for $K_1 + K_2$.